# FadeOut element

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, fadeout

I am trying to fadeout elements using the code

```
$('[title!="head"]').each(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

With the above code, all the elements are fading out including the ones with `$('[title="head"]')`.

The code works perfectly for the condition

```
$('[title="head"]')
```

Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add HTML also

Comment: you should try with :not() selector $(':not([title="head"]')) maybe, but it's weird that it's not working already

Comment: You actually just needed to target *only elements with a title*, then target ones that do not have "head", so `$('[title][title!=head]')` would do the trick. Answer added below. A filter is overkill here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filtering the elements having `title` not as "head"

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/uuvks2ga/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div')
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).attr('title') !== 'head';
    })
    .fadeOut(100);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div title="head">HEAD</div>
<div title="myhead">MY HEAD</div>
<div title="your head">YOur HEAD</div>
<div title="head">Again HEAD</div>
<div title="headNo">HEAD No</div>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using the not equals (`!=`) selector. The problem is the selector in the question itself, which is selecting everything which `!="head"`. The only reason this works is because you're filtering on a collection of `div`s, you could write `$('div[title!="head"]').fadeOut()` and it'd work

Comment: Thank you everyone. The one provided by Tushar worked perfectly, Billy has also made an interesting point.

Comment: It was obviously *not* a problem with DOM ready as "all the elements are fading out". The problem was it matching the `body` element and fading out the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

just use :not()

```
$('body *:not([title="head"])').each (function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

Comment: This will match *all other elements on a page*, so is not specific enough for real world use.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is the problem: `$('[title!="head"]')` will select **everything except elements with `title="head"`**, and then fade them out.

This should make it clearer, consider the following markup:

```
<body>
  <div title="head">Hello World!</div>
</body>
```

Your selector in this example will select `body`, and then fade it out, and as the `<div>` is a child of `<body>`, that'll be indirectly faded out as a result. You'd end up with something like this:

```
<body style="display: none;">
  <div title="head">Hello World!</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

A filter is actually overkill here. The actual problem was targeting all elements including `body` as @billyonecan mentions. Based on the description "all the elements are fading out" there was no problem with DOM ready.

The solution is to target only specific elements e.g. just the items that have a title attribute, then add the `!=head`:

e.g.

```
$('[title][title!=head]')
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/wfp8o9hx/1/

or

```
$('div[title][title!=head]').fadeOut(100);
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/wfp8o9hx/

just preferably something more specific than just `div` :)